# Apache 2.2 - "Split" domain

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, yourls

I'm very new to Apache and already run into an problem which already takes a lot of time and I'm not even sure if it's possible.

I have two servers and one Domain called `szop.in` which is having an `A` record to my first server. On the first server I'm running an URL shortener called YOURLS, it's under `szop.in/admin`. I want the second server serve my homepage, therefor I want to redirect all requests like `szop.in` or `http://subdomain.szop.in` to the second server but not `http://szop.in/admin`.

Is this possible?

This doesn't seem to be the right solution and the `mod_rewrite` is causing me some headache:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} szop.in [NC]
RewriteRule !^/admin$ hxxp://other-domain.in [R=301,L]
```

My idea was, since I need just one URL to work on the first server `http://szop.in/admin`, to redirect everything that is not starting with `/admin` to the other domain.

Comment: `Is this possible?` [Yes, it's possible, give it a try :)](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/intro.html)

Comment: Ok greate, will check it out :). Thanks!

Comment: let me know if that work for u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^szop\.in$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://subdomain.szop.in%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

You cannot use the negation on the `RewriteRule` like that, you use it on a conditions.

This should do what you want, it verify if domain is `szop.in` and if folder is not `/admin` and redirect to `subdomain.szop.in`.

Comment: Worked like a charm :). Thanks for that and sorry that I can't upvote your answer. I have like no reputation :(. Cheers

Comment: @DavidJarosch [you can mark it as the right answer that is as good ;) its the green check below the up and down vote arrows. see here.](http://stackoverflow.com/about)